# ng-click not working in HTML loaded into div

Tags: angularjs-ng-click

I've seen a couple answers but can't seem to figure out how to apply them.

I have a page that's two divs. A side nav div and a main div. On the page load, the js below loads up the html into the main div. The same function is used to jump around (via the nav) within the doc once loaded.

The problem is, there are also links within the HTML to the function since there are some self-referencing points, etc.

The side nav ones work fine, the ones within the HTML don't. I'm assuming it's a compiling issue of sorts, but I can't quite figure out how to compile it correctly.

Here's the JS:

```
Ctrler.loadPage = function(hash){
    if(!hash){
        var url = "filename.html";
        var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
            if (this.readyState!==4) return;
            if (this.status!==200) return; 

            cur = this.responseText;
            cur = cur.replace(/{{sitePath}}/g, jsPath.path);

            document.getElementById('maindiv').innerHTML= cur;
            $('#maindiv').html = this.responseText;
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(hash).scrollIntoView();
        window.scrollBy(0, -90);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I changed the lines that populate the div to this:

```
            $compile(cur)($scope);
            $('#maindiv').append(cur);
```

but it still doesn't work. It loads the first time, but ng-clicks still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I needed to compile `$('#maindiv')` after I added `cur`. Not `cur`